# compress numpy array(matrix) by removing columns using another numpy array as mask

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D `numpy` array (i.e matrix) `A` which contains useful data interspread with garbage in the form of column vectors as well as a 'selection' array `B` which contains '1' for those columns that are important and 0 for those that are not. Is there a way to select only those columns from `A` that correspond to ones in `B`? i.e i have a matrix

```
A = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],   and a vector B = array([ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0])
           [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
           [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

and I want

```
array([[1,   3],
       [6,   8],
       [11, 13],
       [16, 18],
       [21, 23]])
```

Is there an elegant way to do so? Right now i just have a for loop that iterates through `B`.

NOTE: the matrices that i'm dealing with are large, so i don't want to use numpy masked arrays, as i simply don't want the masked data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> A
  array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
         [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
         [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> B = NP.array([ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0])

>>> # convert the indexing array to a boolean array
>>> B = NP.array(B, dtype=bool)

>>> # index A against B--indexing array is placed after the ',' because
>>> # you are selecting columns

>>> res = A[:,B]

>>> res
  array([[ 1,  3],
         [ 6,  8],
         [11, 13],
         [16, 18],
         [21, 23]])
```

The syntax for index-based slicing in NumPy is elegant and simple. A couple of rules cover a majority of use cases:

- the form is **[rows, columns]**
- specify all rows or all columns using a colon ":"  e.g., **[:, 4]** (extracts the
  entire 5th column)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the most efficient way (because of the transposition), but it should be better than a for loop:

```
A.T[B == 1].T
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested to do the same but to slice row & column using the boolean values of vector B,  the solution was simple:

```
res = A[:,B][B,:]
```